# Angular Js scroll slider horizontal Carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider, scroll

I have to use ths type of Carousel in Angular js  [Slider Link](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html) . This is Jquery base slider. How i user this slider in angular js platform. Or please suggest me this type of Carousel in anuglar js.

Comment: you mean the Carousel ?

Comment: you can use angular ui bootstrap carousel for the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use carousel by bootstrap and the directive is available at [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XxPzW/) for the same

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <carousel interval="myInterval">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active" ng-animate="false">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}?{{$index}}" style="margin:auto;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

Comment: it show only one image at a time i am to show multiple images with ajax data load